# has_many through relationship - how to call the join table to print out multiple subcategory's contents?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Goal is to print out the content within each subcategory/subcategories.

I have a list of categories and then subcategories. The subcategories and contents have a has_many :through relationship.  I need to be able to click on one or more subcategories and then show the related contents. Not sure of a couple things:

1) Do I make a subcategories controller and build out the filtering there or go through the contents controller?

2) Should I just make a custom route?

Here is what I have now.

contents table

```
  create_table "contents", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "short_description"
    t.text     "long_description"
    t.datetime "published_date"
    t.datetime "edited_date"
    t.string   "read_length_time"
    t.string   "tag"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.integer  "contenttype_id"
    t.string   "collection"
    t.integer  "collection_id"
    t.string   "subcategory"
    t.integer  "subcategory_id"
    t.boolean  "published"
    t.datetime "created_at",               :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               :null => false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "infographic_file_name"
    t.string   "infographic_content_type"
    t.integer  "infographic_file_size"
    t.datetime "infographic_updated_at"
    t.string   "video"
  end
```

subcategories table

```
      create_table "subcategories", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "title"
        t.integer  "category_id"
        t.string   "content"
        t.integer  "content_id"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

join table
create_table "subcats_contents", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "subcategory_id"
    t.integer "content_id"
  end

  add_index "subcats_contents", ["content_id"], :name => "index_subcats_contents_on_content_id"
  add_index "subcats_contents", ["subcategory_id", "content_id"], :name => "index_subcats_contents_on_subcategory_id_and_content_id"
  add_index "subcats_contents", ["subcategory_id"], :name => "index_subcats_contents_on_subcategory_id"
```

routes.rb

```
  match 'contents/filter_association/:id' => 'contents#filter_association', :as => 'filter_association', :via => :get
```

contents controller

```
  def filter_association
    @subcategory = Subcategory.find_by_id(params[:id])
    Subcategory.where.merge(-> { joins(:content_id) })

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @content }
    end
  end
```

Here is the view for click on the subcategories :

```
<table>
  <% @subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= subcategory.title %></td><br/>
      <td><%= check_box_tag (:subcategory) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<table>
```

ERROR: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Answer (score 0):

You got an error because you didn't pass any params to where method.

If I understood correctly, you are receiving some list of subcategories from the user form and you want to get the list of all contents associated with those subcategories.

```
Content.joins(:subcategories).where(:subcategories => {:id => <variable with subcategory ids>}).group(:content => :id)
```

Comment: Thanks this is definitely closer I just watched http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3?view=asciicast although I'm not sure what you mean by <variable with subcategory ids> - would this be the content id or subcats_contents?

Comment: This is the bit which isn't clear for me from your question. How do you select subcategories for which content is to be displayed? Do you have some kind of form (with checkboxed list or sth?)

Comment: I see. For now I could do check boxes, but in the future I will need to just select the word. Does that help?

Comment: Could you add your view code with the form where you select subcategories to display?

Comment: Great, more questions though. :) First: do you have a form in this view? If so, could you show whole view?

Comment: It isn't a form - this is just on the homepage where the subcategories will be living. I do have a homecontroller that pulls through the content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37085/discussion-between-broisatse-and-lmo)